# Messaging.SharedInstance.Delegate = this is null in xamarin.ios

Tags: xamarin.forms, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

i am trying to integrate fcm in xamarin.ios project in xamarin.forms. i followed the tutorial in this article: https://github.com/xamarin/GoogleApisForiOSComponents/blob/main/docs/Firebase/CloudMessaging/GettingStarted.md#setting-up-a-firebase-cloud-messaging-client-app-on-ios

i added this to my AppDelegate:

```
global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();

            try
            {
                Firebase.Core.App.Configure();
              

                 Messaging.SharedInstance.Delegate = this;


                if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(10, 0))
                {

                    // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
                    UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.Delegate = this;

                    var authOptions = UNAuthorizationOptions.Alert | UNAuthorizationOptions.Badge | UNAuthorizationOptions.Sound;
                    UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.RequestAuthorization(authOptions, (granted, error) => {
                        Console.WriteLine(granted);
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    // iOS 9 or before
                    var allNotificationTypes = UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound;
                    var settings = UIUserNotificationSettings.GetSettingsForTypes(allNotificationTypes, null);
                    UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterUserNotificationSettings(settings);
                }

                UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotifications();

            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"An error occurred: " + ex.Message);
               // Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + ex.Message);
               // Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
                //throw;
            }
            LoadApplication(new App());
            return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
        }
```

but my app crashes on this line:`Messaging.SharedInstance.Delegate = this;` with an exception telling me that it is null. i looked everywhere to find a solution but i couldn't. any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is a know issue for the ios on the github. You can check this issue about [Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.CloudMessaging fails on Messaging.SharedInstance.Delegate](https://github.com/xamarin/GoogleApisForiOSComponents/issues/486).

The issue has appeared two years ago and still not fixed. According to [this comment in the issue](https://github.com/xamarin/GoogleApisForiOSComponents/issues/486#issuecomment-865120629), it only occurs when you develop on the windows. It works if your develop with the MacBook.

You can follow up it or test it on the MacBook.